Sign in to Azure self-host portal using Azure AD not working
I have cloned the Azure self-hosted API Management developer portal code and made several customizations. After completing the customizations, I used the publish command to build the dist folder. Following the official documentation, I copied the contents of this folder to an Azure Storage account to serve it as a static website.
I have configured Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for sign-in. However, when I access the portal, I can view the API list page without signing in. I have followed all the steps to register the application in Azure AD and added the necessary identity configurations.
Sign-in works perfectly for the managed portal, but it does not seem to work for the self-hosted portal. I am unsure what I might be missing in my configuration.
Here are the steps I followed:
Cloned the Azure self-hosted portal repository.
Customized the portal as needed.
Used the publish command to build the dist folder.
Copied the dist folder contents to an Azure Storage account configured for static website hosting.
Configured Azure AD for authentication.
Registered the application in Azure AD and added the identity configurations.
Despite these steps, the API list page is accessible without sign-in, and the self-hosted portal does not enforce authentication as expected.
Can anyone help me identify what I might be missing or suggest additional steps to ensure Azure AD authentication works correctly for the self-hosted portal?
I gave all steps I tried. I want to configure the Azure self hosted portal with Azure AD for sign in.
